# "NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null." Erro in my Stream

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the Error "NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null." from my stream. I tried to change my code several times and added print statements, which get printed correctly, but my Stream ends up returning an error, which is the one from the subject line. Any idea why? How can I Fix the error?

This is the result of the print data statement:

data:

```
{
   userId1: 59jTMEbvqFd8C8UhInksauAVNk63,
   userId2: 2ssfDEPhPhcIwInUWdlm0ReH5RZ2,
   latestMessageTime: Timestamp(seconds=1667140814, nanoseconds=334000000),
   lastMessageSenderId: 59jTMEbvqFd8C8UhInksauAVNk63, 
   created_at: 2022-10-26 19:44:13.793275, 
   latestMessage: TEST 3, 
   roomId: Qv30s8kATJbFJIWRdBEo
}
```

.

```
      Stream<RoomsListModel> roomsStream() async* {
    try {
      // get all active chats
      var rooms = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("rooms")
          .where("users", arrayContains: userId)
          .orderBy("latestMessageTime", descending: true)
          .snapshots();
      print("rooms: $rooms");
// get Other user details
      await for (var room in rooms) {
        for (var doc in room.docs) {
          var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          print("data: $data");
          var otherUser = await getOtherUser(
              data["users"][0] == userId ? data["users"][1] : data["users"][0]);
          print("otherUser: $otherUser");
          yield RoomsListModel(
              roomId: doc.id,
              userId: otherUser["user id"],
              avatar: otherUser["photoUrl"],
              name: otherUser["name"],
              lastMessage: data["latestMessage"],
              lastMessageTime: data["latestMessageTime"]);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }
```

.

```
Future getOtherUser(String id) async {
  // get other user profile
  var user = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(id)
      .get()
      .then((value) => value.data()) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  // return other user profile
  return user;
}
```

Comment: could you add the result of print("data: $data");?

Comment: Just added it. It is actually a little weird, because there should be two rooms, but it is just printing one

Comment: what are you looking for by calling `data["users"][1]`?

Comment: I have a fieldvalue which is an array and contains both user ids who are in a chatroom. I am getting the userid of the other user in order to get his profile image and name to display to his chatpartner.

Comment: as you are see, there aren't any users in that.

Comment: could you also add getOtherUser too?

Comment: Just added it above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
var otherUser = await getOtherUser(
              data["users"][0] == userId ? data["users"][1] : data["users"][0]);
```

to this:

```
var otherUser = await getOtherUser(
              data["userId1"] == userId ? data["userId2"] : data["userId1"]);
```

Comment: The userId2 and userId2 fieldvalues are still from my old model. I actually want to remove them and use the array which I added. The array contains both user ids and makes it easier to do queries

Comment: The array does not get printed somehow...is that normal?

Comment: the data you are geting doesn't contain your userid list, I assume your FirebaseFirestore didn't update. you can check that.

Comment: Just one more question: Now it works fine. But when I call this in my ListView Builder:   itemCount: snapshot.data.length. I get the error: "Class 'RoomsListModel' has no instance getter 'length'." Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: because you are returning a single RoomsListModel not list of it.

Comment: did you get that?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. I have one more question, could I post it and you have a look at it? That would be very nice :)

Comment: yes post it I will look at it.

Comment: I just posted it. Thank you very much!!